# Unable to grep a specifiallyFormatted text

Tags: gcc, grep

I run

```
man gcc | grep "-L"
```

I get

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

**How can you grep the match?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
man gcc | grep -- "-L"
```

Notice the argument "--" which means "don't treat anything that follows as an option".

Also, if you took the advice in the error message to run "grep --help" it would have shown you can also explicitly set the pattern with the -e / --regexp option.

```
man gcc | grep -e "-L"
man gcc | grep --regexp="-L"
```

Comment: @Bryan: Thank you for your answer! It is confusing that Mac's manual for Grep does not have any documentation about the --. @ Is -- a convention in all Unix commands?

Comment: It's been a convention for unix commands for many years, but not all commands follow the convention.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, grep ( and many other gnu commands ) has a "--" option to tell grep that the remainder of the arguments are not to be treated as options to grep.

However, this will only get you lines that have "-L" on them, and that may not give you context. Are you aware that man has a built-in search capability?

```
   man gcc
   /-L
```

Then keep hitting 'n' to see the next match.

Comment: I don't think `man` has a built-in search. It's job it to format the man pages for output. Actual display is handles by a pager, typically "more" or on GNU systems "less". The / search is a function of "less"

Comment: To give the grep search a context, the options -A, -B and -C might be used.

`grep -C 3` will give 3 lines of output context in both directions.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

```
 man gcc | grep -e "-L"
```